# Table cell width declaration is ignored

Tags: css, layout, tablecell

I have an horizontal menu bar that can have from 1 to 4 links.

*I would like that that each link will have a width of 25% not depending by number of them (so in case of only 3 links, menu bar should be only 75% of another one with 4 links).*

Using floats reach the target but in case of longer text spanned across 2 rows, is not possible to adjust other links' height accordingly, so I use `display:table-cell` that solve this issue, but in case of 3 links, completely ignore `width:25%` and it renders like if width would be 33%.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <a href="#">
            Link 3 with very long text tha span across 2 rows
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}

.block {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Please, look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0r22e0y/)** in order to see both cases.

Desired result is that second menubar links continue to have the same width of first one, not becoming 33%.

I tried also to add `table-layout:fixed` as read in other threads but was unuseful

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't know why but you could solve the issue like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bjf1fw8a/

Comment: You can put an empty block at the end: `<div class="block"> </div>` or if you want the whole thing to be shortened you can reduce the width of `container` in the 2nd case to `75%`. But if the width of your container stays at 100% and it's filled with only three elements how should js know what to do with the extra space? It will be filled up to 100% and the width ratios between the different elements determine their contribution.

Comment: You should include enough code (HTML too) in the question itself as needed for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a browser to display a three-column table so that the width of each column is 25% of the total width, you are making a logically impossible request. You cannot have the width of a table to be 75% of itself. Browsers then tend to divide the space evenly to the columns.

A simple fix is to remove `width: 100%` from the rule for `.container` and to set `width: 75%` on the second “table” (`div` element formatted as a table).

Comment: Hi, I can't set a different width for container because number of links change dinamically. Please, see my comment under Bagavatu's answer, to more details.

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question, so that it is understandable without reading answers and comments (which may even be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
var n = $(".container .block").length;
var w = (100/n);
$(".container .block").width(w+'%');
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0r22e0y/4/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, could be a solution, but if possible I would like to remain to a simple css one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about using flexbox?

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  border:solid 1px blue;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
   box-sizing: border-box;        /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

In this way  you can easily adjust your `.block` element's height accordingly...
here's a fiddle with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/o462q4ce/

Comment: using the sintax in the code I provided it should work in IE10 too.
according to caniuse.com IE10 support the 2012 sintax of the Flexible Box Layout Module.
 
source: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: oh, sorry.
I totally misunderstand your comment

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of :last-child and `:nth-child()` selector you can target exactly the `div.block` you need to modify.
Unfortunately using table layout doesn't allow you to manage margin and width as I wish...

anyway here is a solution could fit for your needs

```
.block:last-child:nth-child(3) {width:auto; padding-right:25%;}
.block:last-child:nth-child(2) {width:auto; padding-right:50%;}
.block:last-child:nth-child(1) {width:auto; padding-right:75%;}
```

in this jsFiddle you can see these selectors in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5t0fq1sy/

Comment: Almost, but..... last link in second row is twice long than others. Imagine to have a background applied to .block, and you'll see that it spans across all the container's width....